# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using class from another module

Tags: java, spring, maven

I added dependency of a custom jar(say some-jar.jar) in a module's pom.xml where I need to write my code inside say CustomClass.java. Now, some-jar.jar contains AnotherClass.class which I need to use in my code.

After I finish my code, build succeeds and I am able to successfully deploy the application.

But when the execution reaches my code, it throws an ERROR(not an exception) saying

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/some/package/AnotherClass
. . . and the usual stack trace.
```

I understand this is happening because JVM is not able to locate this file at Runtime even though at compile time it was located, **but what is the solution here? What do I need to do to make it available at Runtime.**

Unfortunately, due to some restrictions I cannot disclose any more information than this issue. Lets see, if it is even required.

Comment: You should add the dependency in pom.xml and make sure you add the class path while you run your jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either specify your dependencies in classpath [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath) or make a **fat jar** (google it)

Comment: Fat jar helped me. Apparently, while deploying the artifacts I missed one. Thanks a lot! :)